# Mybatis mapper with interface instead of xml file

Tags: java, xml, mybatis

I'm working with mybatis this is my configuration and it is working:

`mybatis-config.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
"http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">

<configuration>
    <settings>
        <setting name="cacheEnabled" value="true" />
        <setting name="lazyLoadingEnabled" value="true" />
        <setting name="multipleResultSetsEnabled" value="true" />
        <setting name="useColumnLabel" value="true" />
        <setting name="useGeneratedKeys" value="false" />
        <setting name="autoMappingBehavior" value="PARTIAL" />
        <setting name="defaultExecutorType" value="SIMPLE" />
        <setting name="defaultStatementTimeout" value="25" />
        <setting name="safeRowBoundsEnabled" value="false" />
        <setting name="mapUnderscoreToCamelCase" value="false" />
        <setting name="localCacheScope" value="SESSION" />
        <setting name="jdbcTypeForNull" value="OTHER" />
        <setting name="lazyLoadTriggerMethods"     value="equals,clone,hashCode,toString" />
    </settings>

    <typeAliases>
        <typeAlias type="com.beitech.cagb.secure.api.model.UserDataResult"
            alias="UserData"></typeAlias>
    </typeAliases>

    <mappers>
        <mapper resource="com/payulatam/ppp4/secure/api/interfaces/user-    mapper.xml" />
        <!-- <mapper     class="com.beitech.cagb.secure.api.interfaces.UserMapper" />  -->
    </mappers>

</configuration>
```

`user-mapper.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
"http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="com.beitech.cagb.secure.api.interfaces.IUserDao">

    <select id="getUserData" resultType="UserData">
        select
        usuario_web_id as usuario_web_id,
        tipo_usuario_web as tipo_usuario_web,
        email as email,
        nombres as nombres,
        apellidos as apellidos
        from
        pps.usuario_web u
        where
        u.usuario_web_id=#{userId}
        and u.email=#{mail}
    </select>

</mapper>
```

`IUserDao:`

```
package com.beitech.cagb.secure.api.interfaces;

import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Param;
import com.beitech.cagb.secure.api.model.UserDataResult;

public interface IUserDao {

    public UserDataResult getUserData(
        @Param("mail") final String mail,
        @Param("userId") final Integer userId);

}
```

But if I switch between:

```
<mappers>
    <!-- <mapper resource="com/payulatam/ppp4/secure/api/interfaces/user-    mapper.xml" />  -->
    <mapper class="com.beitech.cagb.secure.api.interfaces.UserMapper" />
```

to use this class instead the xml file `UserMapper`:

```
package com.beitech.cagb.secure.api.interfaces;

import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Select;
import com.beitech.cagb.secure.api.model.UserDataResult;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Results;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Result;

public interface UserMapper {

    @Select("select usuario_web_id as usuario_web_id, tipo_usuario_web as tipo_usuario_web, email as email, nombres as nombres, apellidos as apellidos from pps.usuario_web u where u.usuario_web_id=#{userId} and u.email=#{mail}")
    @Results(value = {
        @Result(property="usuario_web_id",javaType=Integer.class,column="usuario_web_id"),
    @Result(property="tipo_usuario_web",javaType=String.class,column="tipo_usuario_web"),
    @Result(property="email",javaType=String.class,column="email"),
    @Result(property="nombres",javaType=String.class,column="nombres"),
    @Result(property="apellidos",javaType=String.class,column="apellidos")
})
UserDataResult getUserData(String mail, Integer userId);
```

}

I got this error:

`org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found): com.beitech.cagb.secure.api.interfaces.IUserDao.getUserData`

I have this test class:

```
package com.beitech.cagb.secure.api;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import com.beitech.cagb.secure.api.interfaces.IUserDao;
import com.beitech.cagb.secure.api.model.UserDataResult;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations="/META-INF/spring/pu.xml")
public class UserDaoTest {

    @Autowired
    private IUserDao userDao;

    @Test
    public void testUserDAO(){

        Assert.assertNotNull(userDao);
        UserDataResult userDataResult = userDao.getUserData("ana.sandoval@pagosonline.com", 500101);

        Assert.assertNotNull(userDataResult);
        System.out.println("UserData: " + userDataResult.getUsuario_web_id() + " "
            + userDataResult.getEmail() + " "
            + userDataResult.getTipo_usuario_web() + " "
            + userDataResult.getNombres() + " "
            + userDataResult.getApellidos());
    }

}
```

I think maybe is because in the xml file I define a namespace like this and not in the interface:

`<mapper namespace="com.beitech.cagb.secure.api.interfaces.IUserDao">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the in test I should use an instance of the mapper (Interface) to make it work:

```
@Autowired
private UserMapper userMapper;

@Test
public void testUserDAO(){

    Assert.assertNotNull(userMapper);
    UserDataResult userDataResult = userMapper.getUserData("ana.sandoval@pagosonline.com", 500101);

    Assert.assertNotNull(userDataResult);
    System.out.println("UserData: " + userDataResult.getUsuario_web_id() + " "
            + userDataResult.getEmail() + " "
            + userDataResult.getTipo_usuario_web() + " "
            + userDataResult.getNombres() + " "
            + userDataResult.getApellidos());
}
```

Now it works.